# How to add values to Label and Textfields

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I need to know how to populate a `Label` with values from `Store`. In my `Model` i have defined a field called `bookname`. and i need to populate this label with the Book Name.

I know how to do this for a Grid, but don't know how to do it for a `Label` or a `Textfield`.

In Grid;

```
{ text: "Book Name", dataIndex: 'bookname'},
```

But, how can we add values to Label and textfields.

**UPDATE**

i am still having the problem. I am unable to set the values to the Label. (after loading it from STORE). The Label gets displayed but it doesn't get populated with the value that it got from STORE. There's no error as such.

```
Ext.define('Ex.view.info', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.info',
    initComponent: function() {
        var st = Ext.getStore('peopleinformation');
        st.load();
        this.items = [
            {

                xtype: 'label',
                forId: 'myFieldId',
                text: 'My Awesome Field',
                name: 'personfirstname',
                margins: '0 0 0 10'

            }
        ];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why is this down-voted even without a comment .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For just setting a value for label , you can use setText method described in label
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Label-method-setText

```
yourLabel.setText('value');
```

For textField - http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-method-setValue

UPDATE:

```
// in your store
 proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'you url',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },  //your response type like xml, json        
    reader: { type: 'json',            
        getResponseData: function (response) {
            var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            //loop here , if more labels are there
            // get the object referance of label and update that
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:
do you tried:

```
 text: st.yourFieldName,
```

Comment: I need to add, the values after loading from STORE. and i am having the problem displaying the text (from STORE) to the label.

Comment: simple method is from store response you can update your label. included some code

Comment: how do i get the `label` to update. My label is inside a Window. i'm having problems using `ComponentQuery` to locate the label

Comment: if you are creating window from here, you will have handle for that. so you can update the items in that

Comment: what do you mean by `you will have handle for that` ?

Comment: where you are creating that window. there itself you get the store. and update the window. var wind = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {}); wind.item.item[0].setText('yourvalue'); here wind is the handle.

Comment: My window is `Ext.define` and i get into an infinite loop

Comment: No, because, when i click a button the Window should appear as a popup window with some labels in it. So if i use `Ext.create('Ext.window.Window...` the window gets popped out when the application launches it self

Comment: But, what hapence if i want to access that Label again and update the text on it. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Various `fields` are usually combined as items in `form` - (see http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel). Form has a method `getForm().loadRecord(model)` to load data from the model (record in your store) to all fields within the form.

PS: Looks like you haven't gone through Sencha guides (http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide) as I advised you on your other questions. You still don't have general idea of how things work.

Comment: Yes, i have read the Docs. but you can't master it this soon right. i guess trial by error works well.

Comment: I have tried it, and i'm trying to display the record on to a label in a window. it doesn't get displayed, and there's no error shown in firebug. I have added my code in the Post above.

Comment: I don't see in your code anything that takes data from the store and put it into your label.

Comment: ` var st = Ext.getStore('peopleinformation');`loads data from store. and, `name: 'personfirstname',` is a record that i intend to display. :S

Comment: I'm sorry. This is ridiculous. Go and read this guide - http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/data - your code is WRONG on so many levels - I don't know where to start...

Answer (score 0):

Ext 4.1 introduced `setFieldLabel()` on `Ext.form.Labelable` which is mixed into `Ext.form.field.Base`, making it available in `Ext.form.field.Text`.

Thus you can call `myTextField.setFieldLabel("My Label Text")`